# How to prevent nil from being returned when using try

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following line of code:

```
truncate(blog.comments.first.try(:content), :length => 125)
```

Problem here is, where content is empty, this returns `nil`. How can I prevent rails from outputting `nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want an empty string instead

```
truncate(blog.comments.first.try(:content) || "", :length => 125)
```

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, [NilClass](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/NilClass.html) implements a [`#to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/NilClass.html#M000665) which returns `""`, so:

```
truncate(blog.comments.first.try(:content).to_s, :length => 125)
```

However, I'm curious: in what context did you have problems with `nil?` In my experience, erb templates at some point call the explicit conversion `#to_s` and so any type (including nil) that implements the explicit converter will work with no extra effort.